# Not able to login to iChat/Audium using eJabbered 2.1.13

Tags: ios, ejabberd, ichat

I am implementing `eJabbered` chat server using this [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup/) for chat application. I did exactly the same. I am able to add the users using admin panel.

But when I try to login in iChat or Audium it is not allowing me to login. It always shows offline in iChat and in Audium it shows `Server closed the connection`.

Could anyone please help me in solving the problem.
Do I need to add anything?

Comment: What do you found on the ejabberd logs?.  If there is no error messages on it,  try running with higher debug level so it will show connection attempts, data exchange, etc.

Comment: use Psi and enable XMPP console. Copy-paste here the dump of communication